# how to save data from data grid view and textbox in c#

Tags: c#, mysql

i have a 3 text boxes and a data grid view have multi column and I need to save the data to database by using MySql 
i can save the data to database  from text boxes by using Update quire in button1 and save or Update from data grid view by button2 but I need somthing to update and save the data from (Data grid view) and (text boxes) in multiple tables in MySql enter code here

```
 try
        {
            string conn = "Server=" + GlobalsForServerInfo.Server + "; Port=" + GlobalsForServerInfo.Port + "; Database=" + GlobalsForServerInfo.Database + "; Uid=" + GlobalsForServerInfo.Username + "; Pwd=" + GlobalsForServerInfo.Password + ";";
            string Query = "INSERT INTO accounting_sys.add_new_voucher (Voucher_Id,Voucher_Number,Date,Time,Status,Suppliers,Type) values('" + this.txtVoucherId.Text + "' ,'" + this.txtVouNo.Text + "'   ,    '" + this.dtpDateFrom.Text + "'   ,   '" + this.timeEdit1.Text + "'    ,    '" + this.txtStatus.Text + "','" + this.txtSuppliers.Text + "','" + Type + "') ;";
            MySqlConnection MyConn2 = new MySqlConnection(conn);
            MySqlCommand MyCommand2 = new MySqlCommand(Query, MyConn2);
            MySqlDataReader MyReader2;
            MyConn2.Open();
            MyReader2 = MyCommand2.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show("Data Saved");
            while (MyReader2.Read())
                MyConn2.Close();

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

/

```
 private vobutton4_Clickid (object sender, EventArgs e)
        if (txtboxCredit.Text == textboxDebit.Text)
        {
            try //Try section 1 of operation
            {
                dataGridView1.EndEdit(); //very important step
                da.Update(dataTable);
                MessageBox.Show("Data Updated");
                DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show(" Make sure that debit and credit account balances are in the appropriate debit and credit columns of the trial balance calculation. Check for reversed digits and misplaced decimal points.", "Error in transferring account balances to proper trial balance columns",
MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
```

Comment: NEVER concatenate SQL queries/connection string. Use parameterized strings (`string.Format()`)

Comment: can u show me example how to do it in the right way please